# How to generate sequences with distinct subsums?

Tags: sum, distinct, sequence

I'm looking for a way to generate some (6 for default) equations where all subsums are unique.
For example,

```
    a+b+c=50

    d+e+f=50

    g+h+i=50

    a, d and g have to be distinct. 
    a+b and d+e have to be distinct.
    e+f and h+i have to be distinct.
    a+c and d+f have to be distinct.
```

But, a+b and e+f can be the same. So I only care about the subsums of aligned parameters..

I could only found ways to *check* whether some sequence is subsum-distinct, but I found nothing on how to generate such a sequence..

Comment: Are you looking for negative numbers ? Integer solutions ?

Comment: Yes, integer solutions indeed.. I'm sorry.

Comment: The parameters can be negative integers..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state whether you need it to be a random sequence, so suppose that this is not required.

One simple approach is this:

```
1 + 2 + 47 = 50
3 + 4 + 43 = 50
5 + 6 + 39 = 50
7 + 8 + 35 = 50
9 + 10 + 31 = 50
11 + 12 + 27 = 50
```

First two numbers are 2 smallest available numbers, the third number is final sum - those numbers.

a and b are always increasing, c is always decreasing

a + b is always increasing, b + c and a + c are always decreasing

You can generate it this way in a loop.

EDIT after comment that it has to be a random sequence:

Possibly you could create several sets (some sort of hashset/hashmap would be the most appropriate)

1. set of first summands
2. set of sums of first and second summands
3. set of sums of second and third summands
4. set of sums of first and third summands
5. set of previously generated triples

You would generate random triples this way:

1. If total number of demanded triples was not achieved generate a random triple, otherwise finish.
2. Check if the triple was not previously generated, if not proceed with step 3.
3. Conduct checks for first four sets. If no sums are contained within those sets, add triple and proceed with step 1.

However, I am not sure if this approach guarantees that you will get results (especially in small final sums).

So, I would add an counter, if too many consecutive attempts are not successful, then I would switch to brute force approach (which should not be problem if final sums are small and on other hand is very unlikely to happen if a final sum is large).

Overall, performance should be good.

Comment: That's a clever approach, didn't look at it this way before, thanks! But actually, it has to be a random sequence. Any thoughts on that as well..?